# Как найти 2 ближайших числа в списке?

Tags: python, массивы

Есть список, содержащий некоторые цифры:

```
mess = [5, 78, 45, 12, 56, 9999]
```

При вводе числа необходимо найти 2 числа, одно ближайшее наибольшее и одно ближайшее наименьшее

Например: вводим число 8, код выводит 5 и 12 (так как в списке **mess** это ближайшие числа)

Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: напиши алгоритм сначала на человеческом, потом переводи на питонский

Comment: А для единицы что будет в ответе?

Comment: а для 56 что будет в ответе?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mess = [5, 78, 45, 12, 56, 9999]
n = 8

print(max(filter(lambda x: x < n, mess), default=None))
print(min(filter(lambda x: x > n, mess), default=None))
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Так результат для 1 или 100000 получается такой, как нужно?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Функция для поиска двух ближайших чисел в списке mess к заданному числу num
def find_closest_numbers(mess, num):
    # Инициализируем переменные closest_low и closest_high
    closest_low = None
    closest_high = None
    # Инициализируем переменную diff_min значением, которое гарантированно больше всех возможных разностей между числами в списке mess
    diff_min = float('inf')
    # Проходим по всем элементам списка mess
    for x in mess:
        # Если находим число, которое равно заданному числу num, сразу возвращаем его как ближайшее число справа
        if x == num:
            closest_high = num
            break
        # Иначе сравниваем разность между текущим элементом x и заданным числом num с текущим значением diff_min
        # Если разность меньше diff_min, обновляем diff_min и ближайшие числа closest_low и closest_high
        else:
            diff = abs(x - num)
            if diff < diff_min:
                diff_min = diff
                closest_low = x
                closest_high = x
    # Возвращаем два ближайших числа в виде кортежа
    return closest_low, closest_high

# Создаем список чисел
mess = [5, 78, 45, 12, 56, 9999]

# Запрашиваем у пользователя число с помощью функции input
num = input("Введите число: ")
# Проверяем, что введенное значение может быть преобразовано в число
if num.isdigit():
    # Преобразуем строку в число
    num = int(num)

    # Получаем минимальное и максимальное значение в списке mess
    min_val = min(mess)
    max_val=  max(mess)
    # Проверяем, что num меньше наименьшего значения в mess
    if num < min(mess):
        print("Число лежит в диапазон от минус бесконечности до минимального значения в списке mess.")
    # Проверяем, что num больше наибольшего значения в mess
    elif num > max(mess):
        print("Число лежит в диапазон от наибольшего значения в списке mess до плюс бесконечности.")
    # Если num находится в диапазоне значений в mess, ищем два ближайших числа в списке
    else:
        closest_low, closest_high = find_closest_numbers(mess, num)
        # Проверяем, является ли num одним из элементов в mess
        if num in mess:
            print(num, "принадлежит одному элементу mess.")
        # Если num не является одним из элементов в mess, выводим два ближайших числа
        else:
            print("Ближайшие числа к", num, "в списке mess:", closest_low, closest_high)
else:
# Выводим сообщение об ошибке, если введено некорректное значение
    print("Ошибка: введено некорректное значение")
```

Comment: Как-то многовато комментариев....

Comment: На сайте просят расписать подробнее, а не кидать чистый кодярник - поэтому пытаюсь расписать

Comment: Сортировать и затем искать двоичным поиском - неудачное решение.

Comment: задача решается за O(n), а у sorted сложность O(n*log(n))

Comment: @Эникейщик, теперь использую O(n)+ с учетом комментариев , хотя до конца условие не написано :)

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Можно так сделать:

```
mess = [5, 78, 45, 12, 56, 9999]

def search_numbers(lst, num):

    if len(lst) < 2:
        return "Список слишком мал для сравнения"
        
    tmp_prev = []
    tmp_next = []

    for item in lst:
        if item < num:
            tmp_prev.append(item)

        elif item > num:
            tmp_next.append(item)
            
    if not len(tmp_prev):
        return "Отсутствует левое ближайшее число"
    if not len(tmp_next):
        return "Отсутствует правое ближайшее число"
    
    return f"Result: {max(tmp_prev)}, {min(tmp_next)}"
            
num = int(input("Enter number: "))

print(search_numbers(mess, num))
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!